# Vuetify Automcomplete Styling onfocus

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Can we have a outlined custom color in vuetify autocomplete when onfocus. I tried to alter some classes using inspect elements. But nothing worked. Please help

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you need just assign custom `color` attribute value. Have I understood you correct?

```
<div id="app">
    <v-app id="inspire">
        <div>
            <v-autocomplete color="#fa0" 
                            label="Components" 
                            :items="components" />
        </div>
    </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for you reply @Eugen. when i set color it only takes the color of prepend-inner-icon ```    <v-autocomplete
      class="mt-3"
      prepend-inner-icon="fe fe-search"
      append-icon=""
      color="red"
      placeholder="Suche"
      background-color="#EAEFF2"
      ></v-autocomplete>``` here is my code

Comment: I cant see `outlined` attribute in your v-autocomplete component. Is that correct? What is version of Vuetify you use? You may provide some sandbox example too. It would be easier to solve your issue.